# Accessing profiles.clj data from within project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to use Joplin and was thinking about tackling the issue hinted at in this [issue](https://github.com/juxt/joplin/issues/31).

Well, I want to store sensitive information outside of version control. I was thinking of using a `profiles.clj` file with environment information for each database. So, I could make a dev profile with an SQL database username and a password. So inside `profiles.clj`:

```
{:dev {:db {:user "dirtymike" :password "secret"}}}
```

But then in `project.clj`, I have to pass this to the `:joplin` map entry of `defproject`. Is that even possible?

Comment: You should be able to add arbitrary code before `defproject`:
https://gist.github.com/techwhizbang/8887976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ).  It does pretty much what you want to do in a slightly different way.

Comment: I've seen environ around, but I don't think that's what I'm after. Since the Joplin map is defined inside `defproject` in `project.clj` how could I even leverage something like environ to inject profile information into non-profile maps in `project.clj`?

Comment: This might not be the answer you're looking for but: `Boot` can do this (not sure if leiningen can).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this blog post will help you http://blog.martinhynar.cz/2014/10/14/Project-clj-data-into-runtime.html